# YUM root update error

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, updates, yum

I'm getting an error that's new to me when I attempt # yum upgrade in a Fedora 20 Virtualbox machine.  I've given it 3gb ram, and it's running atop a Haswell core i5

Any fixes are appreciated!  Or is it possible this is a remote repository problem?

Terminal output:

```
(process:2094): GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: Parsing primary.xml error: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 355, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 174, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 570, in doCommands
    return self.yum_cli_commands[self.basecmd].doCommand(self, self.basecmd, self.extcmds)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.py", line 494, in doCommand
    ret = base.updatePkgs(extcmds, update_to=(basecmd == 'update-to'))
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 1012, in updatePkgs
    self.update()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 4995, in update
    updates = self.up.getUpdatesTuples()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 1090, in <lambda>
    up = property(fget=lambda self: self._getUpdates(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 836, in _getUpdates
    self._up = rpmUtils.updates.Updates(self.rpmdb.simplePkgList(), self.pkgSack.simplePkgList())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 1071, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 776, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 383, in populateSack
    sack.populate(repo, mdtype, callback, cacheonly)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 260, in populate
    dobj = repo_cache_function(xml, csum)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlitecachec.py", line 46, in getPrimary
    self.repoid))
TypeError: Parsing primary.xml error: Document is empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

That will clear out the cached files in yum's directory and hopefully refresh them with non-broken ones.

Comment: Thanks!  Just ran a big update update sucessfully, I really haven't used that in a while.  This distro is awesome! :D

Comment: Note that personally I always run `yum clean all && yum update yum rpm && yum clean all && yum -y upgrade` when doing large update sets.  If rpm or yum have bugs, I want those fixed before doing the large update.